# Display a field of an object - PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in PostgreSql that performs a calculation and returns an object that contains information separated by `;`

How I can retrieve information from this object using request Postgre?
This is my function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fu_calcul(p_coord_xy geometry, p_id numeric)
RETURNS t_obj
```

Exemple for request :

```
select fu_calcul('01010000206A0800000FB4899BFF6929419300F8907AFE5841', 12)
```

In this case for example, t_obj return `(01010000206A0800000FB4899BFF6929419300F8907AFE5841,0,,0.0973684824407624,3520,212828)` 
I want to retrieve `0.0973684824407624` and its name is `mesure`. i used this request but it does not work :

```
select select fu_calcul('01010000206A0800000FB4899BFF6929419300F8907AFE5841', 12).mesure
```

Comment: Apparently there is no field named `mesure` in the type `t_obj`. What **exactly** is the output of `select fu_calcul('01010000206A0800000FB4899BFF6929419300F8907AFE5841', 12)`

Comment: exactly! I do not have the right name, the right name is `mesure_proj` and not `mesure`. sorry for this bad mistakes from me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [wrap the function call with parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION) to be able to access nested elements of the type:

```
select (fu_calcul('01010000206A0800000FB4899BFF6929419300F8907AFE5841', 12)).mesure
```

Comment: Thank you! it work now but i have to put the right name `mesure_proj` and not `mesure`